# 1004 range of object worksheet failed

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a simple macro, where I create a new workSheet and then set the value of cell A3 to 3, but I am getting this error `method range of object _worksheet failed`

Here is the simple code :

```
Sub testMacro()

    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))

    mySheet.Range(A3).Value = 3
End Sub
```

I am getting the error on line : `mySheet.Range(A3).Value = 3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work;

```
Sub testMacro()

    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))

    mySheet.Range("A3").Value = 3 'Dont forget about ""
End Sub
```